# Latest MySQL version for Windows 7

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How can find out which are the latest GA verions of MySQL Server & Workbench  supported under Windows 7?

On the '[MySQL Product Support EOL Announcements](https://www.mysql.com/support/eol-notice.html)' page it states:

> Per the MySQL Support Lifecycle policy regarding ending support for
>   OS versions that are obsolete or have reached end of life, we plan to
>   discontinue building all MySQL binaries for Microsoft Windows 7 as of
>   June 23, 2016

But I am unable to find information on which versions DO support Windows 7.

**I tried using the installer:**
MySQL Installer-Web seems to be the same for versions 5.6.45, 5.7.27 and 8.17.0 and each of these installers offers me the upgrade of my x64 system to 5.7.27 and my x86 system to 5.7.26.  I would usually take that at face value, and assume the installer was suggesting the latest GA version for my system BUT it also offers me MySQL Workbench 8.0.17 x64, which I know to be *incorrect* because

- it results in an 'You are running an unsupported operating system' message
- [Supported Platforms: MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html)  clearly states that current Workbench only supports Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

From the [code repository](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/commit/191a7d17d0cf87389a0edb928822bb1ac9d987a6#diff-13f013f58160467f9b030ef1bba187e1R223) I see that "Windows 7" was removed from the supported OS list on Oct 3rd, 2018.

```
   static std::vector<std::string> supportedOsList{
-    "Ubuntu 18.04", "Ubuntu 16.04", "Debian 8",
+    "Ubuntu 18.04", "Ubuntu 18.10", "Debian 9",

     "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7", // Oracle 7.1 looks like this: "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release
                                                  // 7.1 (Maipo)"
-    "Fedora release 28", "Fedora release 27", "CentOS release 7",
+    "Fedora release 28", "Fedora release 29", "CentOS release 7",

-    "Windows 7", "Windows 8", "Windows 10", "Windows 2012 Server", "Windows Server 2012 R2", "Windows Server 2016",
+    "Windows 10", "Windows Server 2016",

-    "OS X 10.11", "macOS 10.12", "macOS 10.13"
+    "macOS 10.13", "macOS 10.14"
   };
```

The release after that (8.0.13) was the first one without official Win 7 support.

Comment: So that's the answer for Workbench then.  For MySQL Server I have been trying to look through https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server for similar information.  There is searching for 'supportedOsList' returns no results and it's slow looking otherwise (for something which may not exist).  Do you know where to go for that?

Comment: I doubt there's a similar list for the server in the code base (which would also be way longer). Instead the platform list on the webpage or in the docs is the ultimate source. For the Win7 EOL you have the date already and can use any MySQL version released before that.

Comment: OK, I'll stop looking in the code, thanks.  The Win7 EOL quote says "we plan to discontinue", which isn't exactly definitive.  Using the Wayback Machine on the "Supported Platforms: MySQL Database" page suggests Windows 7 was supported on 20170714 and NOT supported on 20180721, cross referencing to the archived versions release dates suggests Win 7 was supported for 5.7.19, and may have been supported as late as 5.7.23, but is NOT supported for 5.7.24.